# Looking for any biographical info on Terence Haile, author of Space Train

Tags: authors, publishing

We're looking for biographical information about Terence Haile, the author of the science-fiction book "[The Space Train](http://www.risingshadow.net/library/book/40321-space-train)". It's a [very bad book](http://tanaudel.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/space-train-sabotage-sent-them-to-the-skies/), but we are trying to clear the copyright to turn it into an ebook nonetheless!

Unfortunately, Google and Wikipedia are silent on the topic of his biography.

[image]

Comment: It looks like [Digit Publishing](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/publisher.cgi?343), who originally published and presumably held copyright for Space Train only published works from 1955 to 1966, when I presume they were bought or went out of business. US online copyright only goes back to 1978, and I can't find anything else about copyrights held prior to this (in US or UK). :(

Comment: Thanks Josh! I've actuall tracked down Digit Publishing's fate, which is more or less that when their sibling imprints were purchased in the late 1960s, they were left out and effectively ceased to exist. I'm hoping someone somewhere knows the author or his heirs so I can try to get their blessing, regardless of copyright status, which I believe is not a factor here.

Comment: @SingularityCo - Did you ever manage to get hold of any family or biographical info about the author?

Comment: For the record, if anyone reads this, I've got a standing ***1000 rep bounty*** for **any** new info about Terence Haile.

Comment: @Richard They published the ebook, so either they tracked somebody down, or did it anyway: http://singularityand.co/index.php/our-ebooks/our-authors/item/space-train?category_id=30

Comment: @alexwlchan - Indeed. I've asked them via email, via twitter and on their FB whether they managed to track down a relative. Answer came there none. My guess is that they thought "publish and be damned" based on the fact that the book is beyond copyright anyway.

Comment: @Richard : Did you manage to locate a copy of the other novel, *Galaxies Ahead*?  I can't find it, but it might have biographical information, unlike *Space Train*.

Comment: @Richard : It's also worth noting that *Space Train* was reprinted under an alternate name, *The Claw*.  Copies of *The Claw* might have biographical info...

Comment: @Praxis - I'm still looking for those but they're well out of print and copies are hard to come by unless you're willing to spend.

Comment: @Valorum A Terence Haile worked as an engineer, but it might be a different one as the birth dates are different: https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/officers/fn31EsbVXOYiU9YmnCo4taghwQ4/appointments

Comment: @TheAsh - I saw that and chased it a while ago. It's not the same guy. As far as I can tell Haile lived (and died) in the West Midlands.

Comment: Do we know Haile's exact death date?

Comment: @Adamant - 19th January 1979

Answer (score 31):

According to [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?178270), Terence Alfred Haile was born in Birmingham, England on the 22nd June 1921 and died in Walsall, England on the 19th January 1979.

During his lifetime he published two books, "[**Galaxies Ahead**](http://www.risingshadow.net/library/book/40322-galaxies-ahead)" in 1962 and "[**Space Train**](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20407383-space-train)" in 1963 (latterly republished in 1972 as "[**The Claw**](http://cosmiccauldronbooks.com.au/p/claw-terence-haile/)").

For a published author, there is remarkably little information about him on the internet other than what appears to be his [birth record](http://www2.freebmd.org.uk/cgi/information.pl?cite=YD6ZUe5d6APpDyXW79XM8w&scan=1) (below), a [death record](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVZQ-FZV4) and a [possible marriage to a Kathleen T. Dunham](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/search/world-records?firstname=terence&lastname=haile&yearofdeath=1979&yearofdeath_offset=2) in 1969. I couldn't even dig up a photo of the author.

[image: http://www2.freebmd.org.uk/scanpageThumbnail.gif]

According to the probate service, there's also [no record of his having left a will](https://probatesearch.service.gov.uk/Calendar?surname=Haile&yearOfDeath=1979&page=1#calendar).

Quite what he spent the intervening 58 years doing (aside from writing bad sci-fi novels, obviously) is anyone's guess.

> *"Peters, we are over a million years old!" he announced quietly. "When
> we were caught up in that double-sun explosion, we must have been
> carried along in its giddy orbit for over a million years! We were
> kept alive simply because we were in an air-locked compartment and did
> not do anything but sleep for most of the time, thus conserving our
> energy and our bodies to allow us to behave now as if we were normal
> men."'* - <sub><sup>Galaxies Ahead</sup></sub>

Update - Sadly, the original paperback version of his book Space Train [does not contain](https://public-api.wordpress.com/bar/?stat=groovemails-events&bin=wpcom_email_click&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftanaudel.wordpress.com%2F2009%2F02%2F12%2Fspace-train-sabotage-sent-them-to-the-skies%2F&sr=1&signature=888554d90b70fd9413e70a06dd1d8ae0&user=0&_e=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&_z=z) biographical details or an 'about the author'

Comment: FWIW, I have a subscription and can see past the paywall. The marriage information is not very helpful, though, given that there are a surprising number of marriages. A Terence Alfred Haile could easily have another middle name starting with an M or an A.

Comment: @Adamant - Does it indicate the name of his wife?

Comment: Well, sure. But do you have any reason to believe that one marriage is the correct one, rather than another?

Comment: @Adamant - I have reason to believe that this TA Haile is the right one. The biographical details match and Solihull is very close to Birmingham. If it's a coincidence, then it's a big 'un.

Comment: I though you said the '62 marriage. And it looks like Wycombe to Birmingham is quite a bit further.

Comment: Honestly, in your place I'd take a trip to Walsall and look at some old copies of the *Walsall Observer* for obituaries. At least you wouldn't need to take a plane ride.

Comment: I meant the Solihull one. Wycombe to Birmingham is several hours. Birmingham to Solihull is less than 15 minutes

Comment: The '69 marriage is to Kathleen T. Dunham, in any case. Not an uncommon name. :(

Comment: Cheers for that. I'll see if that leads me anywhere.

Comment: Hey, wait. Shouldn't I have put that in my *own* answer? ;)

Comment: Wait, you didn't really need my help with that. ;) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9987?m=22292508#22292508

Comment: @Adamant - Yeah, but you've confirmed it. So that helps.

Comment: Have you looked at copy of *Galaxies Ahead* yet? I see several are available on WorldCat. Also, supposedly there is a copy of *The Claw* in Bundoora.

Comment: @Adamant - I've spoken to a few people with extant copies. There's no bio on the dust-covers and the original publishing company no longer exists and the owner is long dead.

Comment: Some places selling the book *Crevice Rock* list it as being published by Watson Brown, same as *Galaxies Ahead*. Same Haile?

Comment: @Adamant - I believe not. The original publisher for that Cowboy/Western book (and another called "Trail's End") was in the US. It seems likely that it was an import although that's by no means definitive.

Comment: Last time I found biographical information about an obscure British writer was through a comment from a relative of his after grasping online ancestry information of the author as Valorum did.

Comment: @Valorum I await your 1000 bounty!

Comment: @TheAsh - Although this is indeed information, it's not new to me. I already saw these online but discounted them as merely coincidental name/s publishing in America at the same time. Haile was a British author whose (normal) publisher was based in the UK. Although it's not impossible that he also enjoyed success in America outside of his genre, it doesn't seem likely.

Comment: You might get his street address here: https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/midlandselectoral/?name=_Haile&birth=1867&name_x=1_1&pcat=cen_1850&qh=hQClyhI9cK3aWPxsqP9txg%3D%3D

Comment: @Valorum The Sports Stars in Danger: I brought a source proving it was a British book by the same author.

Comment: @TheAsh - Indeed. But the source only contains info that's been taken from the Internet Science Fiction Database (right down to the error in birthdate). I suspect the author of that site has simply searched for the name "Terence Haile" online and copied the details over. Again, I stress how unlikely it is that Haile (a poorly known British author) wrote a book outside of his genre that was published exclusively in the US.

Comment: @Valorum The Sports stars nook was British. And the Western book is British. look at the links and the sources I brought. Abebooks gives a british publisher and 1963.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Death Certificate][image: Haile Dunham wedding][image: Marriage of Hailes' parents]

[image: Electors Register 1945]

Terence Haile was the son of Christopher Haile and Hilda Victoria Aldred. They married in Sparkbrook, Birmingham in 1920.

I have copy of register entry.

Terence was born in 1921. He had at least two siblings, Reginald and Jean. Terence lived with his parents in Birmingham for many years, detail available if this is required, and he married Kathleen Dunham following her divorce from Robert Keith Dunham in 1969. Details available if required. Kathleen died in 1986

Electrician Christopher Haile married Hilda Victoria Aldred at Christ Church, Sparkbrook, Birmingham on 12th June, 1920.

Their son, Terence, was born the following year (General Record Office reference Sep Qtr. Volume 06D page 790). The printed version of this event contains an error and shows his mothers surname to be Alfred, not Aldred. This mistake is also shown on other sites. In the parish register for Christs Church, Sparkbrook, Birmingham, his birth is shown as 22nd June, 1921 and he was baptised on 17th July, 1921. Witnesses were his mother and father and Louise Haile. The family address was 64, Barrows Road.

A National Register was taken on 29th September 1939 and information was used to produce ration cards and identity documents for WW2. The Haile family is shown to be still living at 64, Barrows Road, Birmingham. (Reference: National Archives TNA R39 5577C 015). Terence, a Cost Clerk, is shown living with his parents and a brother, Reginald. There is a “Closed Record” also shown. This may be another sibling called Jean, who was born in 1930. Although of age, no definite record of Terence joining the military has been found. There is, however, an R.A.F. record of a “T. Haile” in 1941. Currently this record cannot be accessed and verified. Although these records were due for release to the National Archives in 2004 they remain with RAF records branch.
In 1945, Terence is to be found on an Electors Register at 124, Medlicott Road, Sparkhill Ward, Birmingham. Later registers show him at this address with his parents and family members up until 1960 or later.

In 1969 Terence married Kathleen Dunham (General Records Office reference September Quarter 1969, volume 9C page 3193) in District of Solihull Terence Haile married Kathleen T M Dunham. This was following her divorce earlier that year*. He died in 1979, Kathleen died in Sandwell on 31st July 1986.  Following a Requiem Mass at the Church of the Holy Name, Great Barr, she was cremated at Newton Road, West Bromwich Crematorium on 6th August 1986.

*Robert Keith Dunham, son of Frank Alban Dunham & Marguerite Elesmore married Kathleen Theresa Mary Finnemore in 1958. The Coventry Evening Telegraph of Saturday 3rd March 1969, page 11, shows details: In a separate case a respondent husband Robert Keith Dunham, of 20, Brook Street, Wolston, on answer, was granted a *decree nisi* on the grounds of desertion by his wife, the petitioner, Kathleen Theresa Mary Dunham. The prayer of the petitioner, also alleging desertion, was rejected.

[image: 1939 register]

To the best of my knowledge there are no direct living relatives. His mother died in 1970 and his father 1976. Reginald died in 1983, Jean was born in 1930 and do not know if she is still alive. Kathleen died in 1986 in Great Barr, Birmingham.

This may not be relevant but the British Library holds a copy of a publication entitled Animals, by a Terence Haile in 1966 Reference BLL 0100156422.

Also in the reference is Solihull. As this place is near Birmingham further research may prove this to be one and the same author.

The Birmingham Mail newspaper of 19th October 1951 includes a letter written by Terence Haile of Sparkhill entitled FAILURE.

> The greatest failure of the Labour Government has been its inability to provide sufficient food for all. Why is it that our defeated enemy, Western Germany, has had no food rationing for years? Is private purchasing of food, as opposed to bulk buying, the answer? Lack in variety in food is responsible for lassitude of thousands of people to-day. The National Health Scheme is not too successful. Many doctors seem to lack interest in the welfare of patients. Is it because of the sluggish way in which they are paid or have they too many patients? Standards of hygiene are lower than ever, in restaurants particularly. The younger generation cannot be blamed when "slap-happy" educational methods are used in secondary schools, which in fact are neither secondary nor modern. Dismiss the cranks of the "Do as you like" mentality, and let us teach children something.

On Monday, October 22nd 1951, an article regarding housing appeared and Terence submitted another letter, entitled Private Builders.

> "When thousands of ex-Servicemen have no hope of getting a house for their families for many years to come, there is obviously something seriously wrong with the Labour Government’s policy. There is a lack of materials but the root cause of the trouble is the refusal of the Government to allow private builders to proceed normally.
> Why have the private builders been treated so shamefully? Let anyone who can, build, and build quickly: blocks of flats, smaller houses-any form of decent habitation for decent, hard-working British people.
> Not having any racial prejudice of any kind, I still think it is madness to allow so many foreign people into this over-populated country, aggravating the already serious housing situation.
> Marriage, child upbringing, sanitation, happiness, health – all these things depend upon good housing conditions. Labour has not helped-can the Tories?"

Was Terence an "angry young man" (he was 30 when this was written) or could he see into the future?

On August 15th, 1952, in reply to a letter regarding sportsmanship and rugby football, printed earlier in the Evening Despatch newspaper, Terence wrote of his personal experiences surrounding soccer, cricket and tennis, declaring “Equally if there were more soccer players, tennis enthusiasts, baseball players, lacrosse experts and athletes, there would be much better relations throughout the world. In short, if mankind was able to devote more time to pleasant pursuits, sport or otherwise, instead of being continually misled by power groups, the world would certainly be a better place”

In 1962 Terence lived at 119, Yoxall Road, Shirley (REF.BCOL and Telephone Directories 1962 to 1973 No. Shirley 5733/021-744-5733) and was making a name for himself as a writer of paperbacks.

A quote from the Birmingham Mail of May 1st 1962 states that

> "He has now turned from Westerns to space fiction. His latest, published today, is "Space Train" (Digit Books)".

The piece goes on to say he was educated at Waverley Grammar School and served in the RAF 1941-1946. While in Rabat, Morocco, he edited a camp newspaper. In civilian life he was a Cost Clerk, assistant surveyor, school teacher, industrial buyer and works manager assistant. His hobbies included music and tennis.

In 1966, at the time of his aunt's death, Terence is shown as a book seller.

Terence Haile married Kathleen Theresa Mary Dunham at the Register Office, Solihull, on the 15th September, 1969.
He was a 48 year old bachelor and gave his profession as a Company Secretary. Kathleen was a 39 year old secretary and her previous marriage had been dissolved (see earlier content). The witnesses were R. Haile (Terence’s brother, Reginald?) and L. C. Finnemore (Kathleen’s brother, Louis Charles?)

Terence Haile  died on 19th January, 1979 at Walsall General (Sister Dora) Hospital. Cause of death was given after a Post Mortem, without an Inquest, as acute left ventricular and pulmonary oedema due to heart failure coronary atherosclerosis.
Information supplied by his widow is that he had been an Assistant Chief Buyer and lived at 32, George Road, Great Barr, Birmingham.

Comment: Where did you get this info and can you offer any specific evidence for this?

Comment: Although I am unrelated to Robert Dunham's family, I have copies of wedding detail of Terence Haile parents, address details for Terence and family from 1945-1960+. Newspaper clip of Kathleen's divorce, prior to marrying Terence. Is this of interest to you?

Comment: Yes, please post it all

Comment: I will have to scan some of these items which may take some time. Is it OK to  upload these to  this site or do you want them directly?  Please advise

Comment: Uploading here would be fine. If you [edit] your answer, you'll see [the button to click for uploading an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9rqc.png).

Comment: I'm especially interested in any biographical details you might have about him, specifically occupation, etc

Comment: In 1939 Terence was shown as a Cost Clerk. I am working through more details and will attempt to post these shortly.

Comment: Is there anything that would allow you to identify a living relative? OP wanted to get clearance to republish their books

Comment: I fixed up the image embedding (currently awaiting edit approval), however, I'm not sure if the order or alt-text is correct for any of the 3 pics.

Comment: "detail available if this is required, and he married Kathleen Dunham following her divorce from Robert Keith Dunham in 1969. Details available if required." Can you share some details?

Comment: I'm pleased that my input has been of some use, although I haven't found living relatives as yet. Terencesnephew, Stewart Haile still lives in Birmingham but haven't tracked him down - yet.

Comment: I have just found Kathleen's death notice. Hope this might move things forward regarding the finding of family members

Comment: @PAULDUNHAM thank you for your research!

Comment: Hopefully I'll  soon be able to post a picture of the elusive Mr Haile.

Comment: You sir, are a absolute demon. A photo of Terence (or details of an extant relative) would likely earn you an additional bonus.

Comment: No picture has been found so far in UK or overseas. More background has been included today and will be updated when available

Comment: @Valorum Paul has found the kill quote that proves that the Western Terence Haile is the Scifi Terence Haile.

Comment: Members of the Haile family have been found and  contacted and I await their reply

Comment: That's an awesome sentiment. Football fans are renowned the world over for their kind and sensible attitudes

Comment: Maybe the world was better in. 1952, just after a second world war?!

Comment: An accident has prevented me from posting for some time. Communications with both Haile and Finnemore family has been made but they are unable or unwilling to assist. I'm back on the case and hope to find more soon

Answer (score 11):

### **He wrote a third book titled "The Sports Stars In Danger", which was not science fiction. He also wrote two Westerns called "Trail's End" and "Crevice Rock".**

[image]

[This website](http://www.authorandbookinfo.com/ngcoba/ha2.htm) seems to have accurate information. It mentions a third, previously unknown, Terence Haile book titled "The Sports Stars In Danger":

> Terence HAILE {UK} (M: 1921 (wrongly 1920) Jun 22 - 1979 (wrongly 1980))
>
> The Sports Stars In Danger [1952]
>
> Space Train [1962]
>
> Galaxies Ahead [1963]

A Google search found a blurb for this book, along with art, from [a British sports horror fan board](http://vaultofevil.proboards.com/thread/596/sport-horror-revamped-version?page=5): It is very Terence Haile-esque:

> Blurb:
> Terence Haile takes you behind the scenes with the glamour of sporting personalities. A murder mystery interwoven with love interest, and exciting descriptive scenes of sporting events brilliantly told by a modern young Author who keeps you in continuous suspense as he unfolds the story of the disappearance of a Famous Sports Star. Mysterious accidents, disagreements between the Sports Stars' Directors, a brutal attack and the discovery of a battered body, the Police on the track of the murderers, a crop of threatening letters, suicide and kidnapping which throws suspicion on many well known sports players. All these events make this a grand, vivid Thriller packed with action that will give lovers of sport the world over continuous enjoyment.

The book is also mentioned in a book called "An Athletics Compendium". It is a compendium of British books on sports. [I found a scanned copy here](http://books.athlos.co.uk/An%20Athletics%20Compendium/files/assets/basic-html/page206.html):

[image]

There is no other record of this book online. Amazon has no copies of it, and neither does Google. It certainly isn't a common book. Quite likely, the [proboards commenter](http://vaultofevil.proboards.com/thread/596/sport-horror-revamped-version?page=5) who posted the cover has no clue that his copy may be one of the last few in existence. The scifi compendiums don't mention it, as it is a regular sports thriller, not science fiction.

The above info seems certain, and I found he also wrote some Westerns. I found one for sale on [Abebooks](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=16566537776&searchurl=an%3Dhaile%2Bterence%26sortby%3D17&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-title7) called Trail's End. It is from the correct time period, published in 1963. It has a British publisher. The Publisher is listed as DIGIT: *the very same as Space Train*!

> About this Item
>
> Brown Watson Wagon Wheel Digit W222 1963 edition paperback, vg In stock shipped from our UK warehouse. Bookseller Inventory # 59742

(Note that the pics are from an [1971 American edition](https://www.ebay.com/itm/TRAILS-END-TERENCE-HAILE-PRIORY-BOOKS-LONDON-PB-MUSTANG-WEST/153440051819?hash=item23b9bd626b:g:ktYAAOSwQXdcpgfJ) of the book. From the back and publication dates though, it is clear that the primary place of publication was England, with all other foreign English-speaking countries sharing a later-published international edition.)  The back of the book reads like something so bad that only he could have wrote it:

[image]
[image]

UPDATE 2022: Found pics of the earlier British edition:
[image]
[image]

Since they share the same publisher, it seems very likely it is the same Terence Haile. In addition, user Adamant mentions that there is another book by Terence Haile called Crevice Rock. UPDATED 2021: I found some pictures on [Ebay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/284298676484?hash=item4231858904:g:lOQAAOSw%7E1pgR1pJ):

[image]
[image]

The listing of the Crevice Rock book says 1961, the same era as Space Train. The writing is extremely similar.

It seems likely that it was primarily published in Britian at first, and it was only later subsequently published in America. (The earliest American edition I could find is 1972, while the British Watson Brown published the books in the 1960's.) There is almost zero chance that there were two Terence Hailes with poor writing skills with the same publisher in the same time period.

Although it may seem unlikely that small-time author Terence Haile had American editions of his books, he seems to be popular enough to have German translations of his books:

[image]

[image]

I can't seem to find confirmation that these were direct translations from Terence Haile that wrote the Westerns above, but it comes from a list that contains definite non-Germanic authors and seems to be from the correct time period. However, the titles are different, but it seems likely that the translator just changed the titles, as there are hardly any chance that there was two Terence Hailes writing bad science fiction and westerns. (EDIT: User Oliver has confirmed the books are the same.)

Comment: I believe those are a different Terence Haile. The Western novel, certainly was originally published in America, an unusual choice for a British author

Comment: The Sport Star book appears to have info taken from the ISFDB without authentication. It's likely (unless there's another source to confirm that they're the same person) that they've simply seen the name online.

Comment: @Valorum The Western novel clearly was not originally published in America: The Abebooks gives a publication date of 1963 for the British one, while the American editiuons list 1971.

Comment: @Valorum The Sports one is British - there is ZERO chance of two Thomas Heales with poor writing skills both published authors in that time period. And they did not take info from the scifi databases - otherwise A) they would have added the westerns B) They have to have gotten the incorrect dates from somewhere in order to correct them. Thus, they have a different source.

Comment: @Valorum from Abebooks: For the western:  Brown Watson Wagon Wheel Digit W222 1963 edition paperback, DIGIT was Mr. Trence Haile's publisher.

Comment: @Valorum I added the Western's publishing info to the answer, with the quote that it's from DIGIT. Thus, I await the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. That they're published by the same obscure publisher is a big boost. Even if this turns out to be a different Haile, it's certainly useful new info because we'll know we're chasing two ghosts, not one.

Comment: I would still love some biographical detail about him, especially his life history. I'll repost the bounty once yours is finalised.

Comment: @Valorum me too. I just added in that it is highly unlikely for there to be two British authors named Terence Haile from the same time period.

Comment: If Trail's End is correct, what about Crevice Rock, the other one that I found?

Comment: @Adamenr it probably is, and I imagine that's what the two German books were (though they must of changed the title). I can't find original publication info for Crevice Rock in Britian though.

Comment: They have a copy at the National Library of Scotland. It might be worth a look. It should be easier to get it as an loan in Britain.

Comment: @Adamant I can't find any record of Crevice Rock online. Where did you find it? EIther way, since BOTH westerns he published shared the same publisher as his other book, it seems to be quite clear that yes, it is 100% the same Terence Haile. I would like to find a record of that book so I can update my answer with conclusive proof. There's no way that twice there was a coincidence.

Comment: "Crevice rock" is indeed "Colorado Western Story 240" by Publisher Pabel verlag, translated in 1965. best, Oliver (pulverrauch.de - biggest western literature website in german)

Comment: @oliver did they translate Space Train as well?

Comment: @oliver added pics of the book. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Valorum Added pics of Crevice Rock, 1961 edition. See the back, definitely the same author.

Comment: @TheAsh - So, our Terence was a writer of both bad science fiction *and* bad Westerns. I remain intrigued about his real life persona. I have visions of him toiling in obscurity, building crystal palaces in his imagination.

Comment: The British Library has a copy of Sports Stars in Danger: http://explore.bl.uk/BLVU1:LSCOP-ALL:BLL01001564224

Comment: [Also](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?fn=search&vl(freeText0)=Haile%2c+Terence.&tab=local_tab&mode=Basic&scp.scps=scope%3a(BLCONTENT)&vid=BLVU1&ct=suggestedSearch&vl(2084770705UI1)=all_items&vl(2084770704UI0)=creator) _Space Train_, _Galaxies Ahead_, and a juvenile book called _Animals_.

Comment: @Valorum What ever you want to say about him, he has infinitely more books published than I do!

Comment: @Valorum shoover just deserved your ongoing 1000 bounty (if that's still going on) by finding a sixth unknown Terence Hailey book.

Comment: @shoover write that as an answer. Valorum has an ongoing bounty for new info on Terence Hailey and you just found something new!

Comment: @shoover - The dates and location certainly align (1966 and mention of Solihull). Can you find out anything else about this 'Animals' book?

Comment: Added pics of the earlier edition of Trails End